# Failed to update txpool transaction metadata on local Monero daemon

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, blockchain, txpool, keys-file

I have a Monero daemon running on a **Raspberry Pi** connected to my LAN. After a full blockchain sync, I got this error:

```
2018-01-16 12:00:50.993  [P2P0]  ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:516     Failed to update txpool transaction metadata: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
```

Everything seems to be working fine and I can use the daemon from a wallet on another PC over the LAN without issues. The error message has appeared once and if I use the `´status´` command, I get this result:

```
Height: 1488428/1488428 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 669.57 MH/s, v6, up to date, 9(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 6h 3m 33s
```

What should I expect from such an error?

What should I do about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not a problem. While it might happen for several reasons, the most likely is benign: monerod attempted to relay a transaction from the txpool to other peers, but then failed to record the relay time as the transaction was not in the txpool. This happens when the transaction is taken off the txpool when it's mined in a block at the same time it gets relayed.

See https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2971/files for a fix (which doesn't change the way it works, just makes sure there's no error when it's the benign case).